# Reference current bean with SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-el

Is there a way to reference the current instance of the object which contains the SPeL expression?

I am basically looking for something like

```
@Value("#{otherBean.getClassName(this.GetClass())}")
```

Where `getClassName(Class<T> class)` returns the name of the class, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; that is not possible; there is no way to reference the current bean (or class), you can only access beans by name.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this was the case but wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.